# Running Django test server on Amazon instance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, amazon-web-services, django

I am trying to run basic Django app on Amazon like:
managy.py runserver 80

It starts running, but I can't connect to Django from browser to this port, FF can't connect.
My Security Groups are set up ok, since I can connect to Apache from outside, if I run it.

Is there a way to use django runserver on Amazon?
Or more production-like stack, with Apache, is strongly adviced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that will only bind it to 127.0.0.1:80. You need to run the following

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

That will make it work via the all ips on the server which you will be able to hit from your location if your security groups are open for port 80